# Next _buildmanifest.js and _ssgmanifest.js 404 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, next.js, digital-ocean

Next: 12.3.4

React: 17.0.2

Node: 16.13.1

I have this issue on my next js application.
Where the console will show on all pages that I load the following error:

`404 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

regarding both: `_buildmanifest.js` and `_ssgmanifest.js`

Even if I run it locally using `npm run build` and `npm start` I am getting this issue.

I see that files do exist but with different casing, can it be related?
On my windows 11 the file is located at:

`client\.next\static\io6UEfAcy-3AhaJtH2vQE\_buildManifest.js`

And I see that the 404 is at:

`http://localhost:3000/_next/static/io6uefacy-3ahajth2vqe/_buildmanifest.js`

Can it be related? it also happened if I try to deploy it to Digital Ocean, which I assume is linux system. But if I cd inside the console to this file, there's also the casing issue.

I tried to search this issue and all topics I found suggested to restart the next server, I tried that, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on next@14.0.4

1. Delete node_modules, .next folder
2. Install node_modules
3. I deleted every file from public folder
4. Run build
5. see if build runs successfully and add public folder's files back

I am not sure why this error appeared, but by following that steps from above, it is gone. It builds now without errors, without having to remove node_modules and public folder's files.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened because I had a middleware that modified urls to make all letters lowercase, and it messed up the native URLs,once disabled the problem was fixed